# Connecting Smartsheets with Celonis

Tags: url, redirect, uri, smartsheet-api

i am trying to connect Smartsheet with Celonis. I already have a Client ID and Client Secret but everytime I try to connect both, Smartsheets shows an error saying Redirect URL ist missing or wrong. Thanks in advance

In the developter Settings of Smartsheet it asks for the APP URL and APP Redirect URL. I am currently still uncertain what to fill out in both fields.
As the App which wants to get the Data Sheet is Celonis, I have filled in an APP URL with the Celonis URL (something like -> https://xyz.celonis.cloud/package-manager/ui/studio/ui/assets/xxxyyy-11-123) and an APP redirect URL the Authorization Page URL (something like this -> https://app.smartsheet.com/b/autorize?form.....) and every other mixture of these and other URLs but nothing seems to work out.
I have also reviewed various Smartsheet Docs but found no answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

First, registering an app in Smartsheet in the way that you’ve described is only necessary if your integration between Celonis and Smartsheet will use [OAuth](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/OAuth-Walkthrough) (i.e. Celonis will ask the user for permission to access their Smartsheet data and if approved by the user, then Celonis will be able to programmatically access the user’s Smartsheet data). Is this the functionality you’re trying to achieve?

If NOT (i.e. Celonis doesn’t need to make API calls as each specific user that connects to Celonis) — then you don’t need to register the app in Smartsheet. Just create an access token in Smartsheet for the app to use, and make sure the user (account) that owns the token has permissions to access the necessary sheets in Smartsheet.

If YES (you are trying to implement OAuth so that Celonis can access the Smartsheet data of the user that’s logged into Celonis)….then here’s some info about those two fields:

- **App URL** is just the application’s main URL. For example, if I was implementing Smartsheet OAuth in my app where the home page was `http://www.abctest123.com` then that’s the value I’d enter in the **App URL** field when registering the app in Smartsheet. As far as I know, this field isn’t used for anything in the OAuth process — it’s purely for reference purposes.
- **App Redirect URL** is the address of the page in your app where the user will be redirected after they choose **Allow** or **Deny** when they’re asked whether or not Celonis can access their Smartsheet data. This needs to be a valid page URL, for a page that you’re able to configure to read any query string parameters that are present in the URL — because when redirecting the user to that page, Smartsheet uses query string parameters to indicate whether the user allowed or denied access, and if they allowed access, to specify the authorization code and expiration info for that code.

If you need more info, the OAuth process is described very well in the Smartsheet Dev Docs: https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/OAuth-Walkthrough.